Performance of incrementing counters in YugabyteDB YSQL
I have 1,000 components each has a separate table row that it update every 10 seconds.
I currently use redis with HSET and HGET.
Is it reasonable to use ysql for this?
Will frequent updates create bloat?
Is automatic full compaction enabled on stable and will take care of that?

I did a quick test by running:
create table counter(name text primary key, value bigint default 0);
insert into counter(name) select generate_series(1,100000);
select pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('counter')) \;
explain (analyze, costs off, dist) update counter set value=value+1 ;
\watch 0.001

Continuously updating 100000 counters every 5 seconds since you asked.
The time to update didn't increase. The time to query one row stays the same (10 milliseconds). The size stays with 5 SST files (rocksdb_level0_file_num_compaction_trigger) for 150MB which shows that there's no need for full compaction. The WAL stays at 600MB as it keeps 15 minutes of changes (timestamp_history_retention_interval_sec) in case a replica is temporarily down and has to re-synchronize.


I did some test some times ago:
https://dev.to/yugabyte/in-memory-counters-with-yugabytedb-2p54
It shows the same: universal compaction works well with this pattern
